# New NCover 3.4.2 makes all my MSTest unit tests fail

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, code-coverage, ncover

Yesterday, I decided to install the newest NCover version (3.4.2). However, when I ran it on my existing .ncover configuration file, the NCover output suddenly reported that all my MSTest tests failed. Of course those tests succeed when ran within Visual Studio. Because of this, NCover isn't able to determine any coverage.

Somehow the old configuration doesn't seem to work with the new version.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be or how to solve it?

Btw. Here is my ncover configuration.

Project settings:
Path to application to profile:
*c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe*

Arguments for the application to profile:
*/testcontainer:D:\dev\MyApp\MyApp.Services.Tests.Unit\bin\Debug\MyApp.Services.Tests.Unit.dll /testcontainer:D:\dev\MyApp\MyApp.WS.Tests.Unit\bin\Debug\MyApp.WS.Tests.Unit.dll*

Working folder:
*D:\dev\MyApp*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, and it had (of course) nothing to do with NCover. The problem was that MSTest.exe couldn't find one of my test assemblies. This assembly was only referenced in the configuration file and wasn't used in code. When run within Visual Studio, this works. Running outside of Visual Studio failed.